# Prove that if $f$ is continuous on an open interval, then there is a $c \in I$ such that $f(c)=r$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, continuity

Let $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval. Let $f \colon D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function with these properties:

1. $f$ is continuous in $D$.
2. $\exists x_0 \in D$ such that $f(x_0)=0$.
3. There exists $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a < 0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x)=a$.

Can you give me any insight on how to prove that, for all real number $r$ s.t. $a<r \leq 0$, there is a $c \in D$ such that $f(c)=r$? Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $f\colon D\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ instead of $f\colon I\longrightarrow\Bbb R$?

Comment: Your requirement supposes $a\le 0$.

Comment: You still have an unexplained $I$.

Comment: I believe now it is all set. Thank you for the flags

Comment: If $f$ is defined only on $D$, how can it have a limit as $x \to \infty$?

Comment: the reason I thought is that $D$ is an open interval without upper bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using Intermediate Value Theorem (IVT).

Since $f$ is continuous in $D$ (and $D$ is an interval), we can define the interval $D_2$ as a subset of $D$, where $D_2 = [x_0, \infty)$. We know that $$f(x_0) \neq a = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$$

hence we can apply IVT. Choose arbitrarily $r \in \mathbb{R}$ where $a<r\leq 0$. By IVT, we know there exists a $c \in D_2$ (therefore $c \in D$) such that $f(c) = r$.